# Want Section and Subsection page slide At the end of Each Section

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,compress,t,fleqn]{beamer}

\makeatletter   % add "\color{blue}" to argument of "\maketag@@@"
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{strawberry}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatother

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\renewcommand\mathfamilydefault{\rmdefault}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}}
% Version for handouts
% \documentclass[handout,red]{beamer}
% \usetheme{Rochester}
% \usepackage{pgfpages}
% \pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Copenhagen} %\usetheme{Szeged} % \usetheme{Malmoe}  %\usetheme{Berlin} \usetheme{cambridgeUS} % \usetheme{copenhagen} %AnnArbor %Boadilla
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue!90!black}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \placelogotrue
  \begin{frame}\frametitle{Next Chapter}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Part 2}
\subsection{Part 3}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Part 1}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can only see a code example and the title doesn't fully explain the question to me (and maybe others too). Can you please elaborate what you are looking for a little?

Comment: Why are you using `\section` and `\subsection` inside a frame? That doesn't make any sense. A `\section` or a `\subsection` contains one or more `frame`s, so the proper hierarchy would be `\section{Foo}\subsection{Bar}\begin{frame}...\end{frame}\begin{frame}...\end{frame}\subsection{Bar}\begin{frame}...\end{frame}`

Comment: Well, I want to show the section title and subsections on a single page slide before each section of the presentation starts. Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: I corrected the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
  \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
```

at the beginning of each section. A complete example (I deleted parts of the code in the question that were not esential for the problem here):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,compress,t,fleqn]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue!90!black}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\chaptername~\thesection}
  \vfill
  \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\subsection{Test subsection one one}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection one two}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\subsection{Test subsection two one}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two two}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two three}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the outline for section one:

[image]

An image of the outline for section two:

[image]

Comment: Gonzalos is it possible we could have Chapter 1 Chapter 2 and so without having Next Chapter on top of each frame? Thank you.

Comment: @user28251 Sure. Please see my updated answer.